# How to create a complicated boxplot grouped on one continuous and one factor variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to replicate the boxplots in a paper looks like this:

[image]

The boxplots are grouped by one continuous variable (I - indexed on x-axis) and one factor variable (Method - indexed by color).

Here's my replicates, everything looks fine but the groups of boxplots are not placed according to the value of the continuous variable:

[image]

My code is listed below:

```
df5 <- data.frame(
  I = factor(rep(c(50, 100, 200, 400), each = dim(df1)[1])),
  rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)
)
ggplot(df5, aes(x = I, y = Values*1e05, fill = Method)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#FF7F00")) +
  labs(x = "I (Number of subjects)", y = expression(paste("MISE(", beta[1], "(s))(x", 10^-5, ")"))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I have to say that I need to change the type of the continuous variable to factor to correctly display four groups of boxplots. But the groups of boxplots are now equally spaced (not according to the value of continuous variable: 50, 100, 200, 400).

Could you please give me some hint about how to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the variable you map on `x` aka `I` is a `factor` not a `numeric`. Hence, to achieve your desired result convert `I` to a `numeric`. Additionally, to make this work you also have to explicitly map on the `group` aes so that the box plots still get grouped by `I` and `Method`. To this end I map `interaction(I, Method)` on `group`. Finally, I use `scale_x_continuous` to set the breaks according to the values of `I` in your data.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- expand.grid(
  Method = letters[1:4],
  Values = seq(100)
) |>
  transform(Values = runif(400))

df5 <- data.frame(
  I = factor(rep(c(50, 100, 200, 400), each = dim(df1)[1])),
  rbind(df1, df2, df3, df4)
)

library(ggplot2)

df5$I <- as.numeric(as.character(df5$I))

ggplot(df5, aes(
  x = I, y = Values * 1e05,
  fill = Method,
  group = interaction(I, Method)
)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#FF7F00")
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df5$I)) +
  labs(
    x = "I (Number of subjects)",
    y = expression(
      paste("MISE(", beta[1], "(s))(x", 10^-5, ")")
    )
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]